# height of the list component at ireport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I have a list component in my report that displays a set of data.Its height is determined during runtime according to the size of the Set(JRBeanCollectionDataSource).I want to create a rectangle whose height is the same as the list.How can i do this? Thanks.

Update:[image]

Update 2: ireport look
[image]

```
<frame>
                <reportElement x="0" y="127" width="502" height="548"/>
                <frame>
                    <reportElement x="21" y="0" width="460" height="180"/>
                    <componentElement>
                        <reportElement x="203" y="0" width="257" height="55"/>
                        <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                            <datasetRun subDataset="dataset1">
                                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{inventors})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                            </datasetRun>
                            <jr:listContents height="55" width="257">
                                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                                    <reportElement x="50" y="0" width="47" height="18"/>
                                    <textElement>
                                        <font pdfEncoding="Cp1254"/>
                                    </textElement>
                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                </textField>
                                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                                    <reportElement x="97" y="0" width="100" height="18"/>
                                    <textElement/>
                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{surname}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                </textField>
                                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                                    <reportElement x="72" y="18" width="100" height="18"/>
                                    <textElement/>
                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{department}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                </textField>
                                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                                    <reportElement x="61" y="36" width="100" height="18"/>
                                    <textElement/>
                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{appellation}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                </textField>
                                <line>
                                    <reportElement x="0" y="54" width="256" height="1"/>
                                </line>
                                <line>
                                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="1" height="54"/>
                                </line>
                                <line direction="BottomUp">
                                    <reportElement x="256" y="0" width="1" height="54"/>
                                </line>
                            </jr:listContents>
                        </jr:list>
                    </componentElement>
                    <rectangle>
                        <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="61" y="0" width="142" height="164"/>
                    </rectangle>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="73" y="7" width="119" height="63"/>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="12" isBold="true" pdfEncoding="Cp1254"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[Buluş Bildiren Çalışan’ın Adı/Soyadı/Bölümü/Görevi]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <rectangle>
                        <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="61" height="164"/>
                    </rectangle>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="10" y="7" width="40" height="139"/>
                        <textElement rotation="Left">
                            <font size="10" isBold="true" pdfEncoding="Cp1254"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[BULUŞ BİLDİREN ÇALIŞANLARLA  İLGİLİ BİLGİLER]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                </frame>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="21" y="180" width="459" height="139"/>
                    <textElement markup="none">
                        <font pdfEncoding="Cp1254"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.]]></text>
                </staticText>
                                </frame>
```

Comment: Is this a border for a list component or this is a independent rectangle?

Comment: it is an independent rectangle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put `List` element and `Rectangle` in `Frame` container.

The sample:

```
<detail>
    <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ADDRESS_FIRSTNAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ADDRESS_CITY}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <frame>
            <reportElement x="200" y="0" width="324" height="20"/>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="155" height="20"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="dataset1">
                        <datasetParameter name="addressId">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{ADDRESS_ID}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="20" width="155">
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="62" height="20"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Total docs: " + $F{DOCUMENT_TOTAL}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="155" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            </rectangle>
        </frame>
    </band>
</detail>
```

You should set ***`stretchType`*** property for *rectangle* as **`RelativeToTallestObject`** and set *textField's (lying in list)* ***`isStretchWithOverflow`*** property as **`true`**.

The result will be:

[image]

Comment: thank you Alex it works..now the problem is,how can i calibrate the position of the field/rectangle which is right below the list?because when the list is short,there is a gap between them and when the list is long,it overflows to the below field/rectangle.

Comment: Could you please add the image for better understanding your problem. May be you should create a new question?

Comment: actually i didnt create a new question because the problem is still about the height of the list component at ireport.I added an image to the question for you to understand the problem better.when the people list has 1 or 2 element there is a gap between the list and the loreen ipsum text,when it has 3 elements everything is alright,when it has more than 3 elements(as in the image) list overflows to the text which is below it.

Comment: Is the long textfield is below of list? Could you post the screenshot of your report template (how it is looks in iReport)?

Comment: Yes,static text is at below of the list.i added the ireport appearance screenshot.thanks

Comment: You should set for this staticText `positionType="Float"`

Answer (score 1):

You also can try with these properties,

```
<staticText positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject">
   <reportElement x="21" y="180" width="459" height="139"/>
      <textElement markup="none">
          <font pdfEncoding="Cp1254"/>
      </textElement>
   <text><![CDATA[Lorem Ipsum ....]]></text>
</staticText>
```

[image]